# Why won't my compiled GWT project run in a browser?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a GWT project which is very very simple:  it's one module with a single EntryPoint that just calls `GWT.log` in order to tell me that it has compiled and run successfully.

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;

public class Tester implements EntryPoint {
    public void onModuleLoad()
    {
        GWT.log("I have compiled and run successfully");
    }
}
```

It does compile - it spits out a bunch of files in the WAR folder.

My understanding of what I need to do to run it (based on http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html) is that I need to run the `hosted.html` file in a browser and it will do all of its magic.  I've put the entire WAR folder on a HTTP server (so that it can get the other files without being blocked by file:// stuff like I've had issues with in web development before) and fetched it in Chrome.  It does nothing.  I looked at the network monitor in it and recorded while refreshing the page - the only file ever loaded is `hosted.html`:

[image: Chrome network monitor showing only hosted.html being fetched]

There are no errors or messages in the JavaScript console...

The resulting hosted.html is as follows:

```
<html>
<head><script>
var $wnd = parent;
var $doc = $wnd.document;
var $moduleName, $moduleBase, $entry
,$stats = $wnd.__gwtStatsEvent ? function(a) {return $wnd.__gwtStatsEvent(a);} : null
,$sessionId = $wnd.__gwtStatsSessionId ? $wnd.__gwtStatsSessionId : null;
// Lightweight metrics
if ($stats) {
  var moduleFuncName = location.search.substr(1);
  var moduleFunc = $wnd[moduleFuncName];
  var moduleName = moduleFunc ? moduleFunc.moduleName : "unknown";
  $stats({moduleName:moduleName,sessionId:$sessionId,subSystem:'startup',evtGroup:'moduleStartup',millis:(new Date()).getTime(),type:'moduleEvalStart'});
}
var $hostedHtmlVersion="2.1";

var gwtOnLoad;
var $hosted = "localhost:9997";

function loadIframe(url) {
  var topDoc = window.top.document;

  // create an iframe
  var iframeDiv = topDoc.createElement("div");
  iframeDiv.innerHTML = "<iframe scrolling=no frameborder=0 src='" + url + "'>";
  var iframe = iframeDiv.firstChild;

  // mess with the iframe style a little
  var iframeStyle = iframe.style;
  iframeStyle.position = "absolute";
  iframeStyle.borderWidth = "0";
  iframeStyle.left = "0";
  iframeStyle.top = "0";
  iframeStyle.width = "100%";
  iframeStyle.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
  iframeStyle.zIndex = "1";
  iframeStyle.height = "100%";

  // update the top window's document's body's style
  var hostBodyStyle = window.top.document.body.style; 
  hostBodyStyle.margin = "0";
  hostBodyStyle.height = iframeStyle.height;
  hostBodyStyle.overflow = "hidden";

  // insert the iframe
  topDoc.body.insertBefore(iframe, topDoc.body.firstChild);
}

var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
if (ua.indexOf("gecko") != -1) {
  // install eval wrapper on FF to avoid EvalError problem
  var __eval = window.eval;
  window.eval = function(s) {
    return __eval(s);
  }
}
if (ua.indexOf("chrome") != -1) {
  // work around __gwt_ObjectId appearing in JS objects
  var hop = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(prop) {
    return prop != "__gwt_ObjectId" && hop.call(this, prop);
  };
  // do the same in our parent as well -- see issue 4486
  // NOTE: this will have to be changed when we support non-iframe-based DevMode 
  var hop2 = parent.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
  parent.Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty = function(prop) {
    return prop != "__gwt_ObjectId" && hop2.call(this, prop);
  };
}

// wrapper to call JS methods, which we need both to be able to supply a
// different this for method lookup and to get the exception back
function __gwt_jsInvoke(thisObj, methodName) {
  try {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return [0, window[methodName].apply(thisObj, args)];
  } catch (e) {
    return [1, e];
  }
}

var __gwt_javaInvokes = [];
function __gwt_makeJavaInvoke(argCount) {
  return __gwt_javaInvokes[argCount] || __gwt_doMakeJavaInvoke(argCount);
}

function __gwt_doMakeJavaInvoke(argCount) {
  // IE6 won't eval() anonymous functions except as r-values
  var argList = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < argCount; i++) {
    argList += ",p" + i;
  }
  var argListNoComma = argList.substring(1);

  return eval(
    "__gwt_javaInvokes[" + argCount + "] =\n" +
    "  function(thisObj, dispId" + argList + ") {\n" +
    "    var result = __static(dispId, thisObj" + argList + ");\n" +
    "    if (result[0]) {\n" +
    "      throw result[1];\n" +
    "    } else {\n" +
    "      return result[1];\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "  }\n"
  ); 
}

/*
 * This is used to create tear-offs of Java methods.  Each function corresponds
 * to exactly one dispId, and also embeds the argument count.  We get the "this"
 * value from the context in which the function is being executed.
 * Function-object identity is preserved by caching in a sparse array.
 */
var __gwt_tearOffs = [];
var __gwt_tearOffGenerators = [];
function __gwt_makeTearOff(proxy, dispId, argCount) {
  return __gwt_tearOffs[dispId] || __gwt_doMakeTearOff(dispId, argCount);
}

function __gwt_doMakeTearOff(dispId, argCount) {
  return __gwt_tearOffs[dispId] = 
      (__gwt_tearOffGenerators[argCount] || __gwt_doMakeTearOffGenerator(argCount))(dispId);
}

function __gwt_doMakeTearOffGenerator(argCount) {
  // IE6 won't eval() anonymous functions except as r-values
  var argList = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < argCount; i++) {
    argList += ",p" + i;
  }
  var argListNoComma = argList.substring(1);

  return eval(
    "__gwt_tearOffGenerators[" + argCount + "] =\n" +
    "  function(dispId) {\n" +
    "    return function(" + argListNoComma + ") {\n" +
    "      var result = __static(dispId, this" + argList + ");\n" +
    "      if (result[0]) {\n" +
    "        throw result[1];\n" +
    "      } else {\n" +
    "        return result[1];\n" +
    "      }\n" +
    "    }\n" +
    "  }\n"
  ); 
}

function __gwt_makeResult(isException, result) {
  return [isException, result];
}

function __gwt_disconnected() {
  // Prevent double-invocation.
  window.__gwt_disconnected = new Function();
  // Do it in a timeout so we can be sure we have a clean stack.
  window.setTimeout(__gwt_disconnected_impl, 1);
}

function __gwt_disconnected_impl() {
  __gwt_displayGlassMessage('GWT Code Server Disconnected',
      'Most likely, you closed GWT Development Mode. Or, you might have lost '
      + 'network connectivity. To fix this, try restarting GWT Development Mode and '
      + 'refresh this page.');
}

// Keep track of z-index to allow layering of multiple glass messages
var __gwt_glassMessageZIndex = 2147483647;

// Note this method is also used by ModuleSpace.java
function __gwt_displayGlassMessage(summary, details) {
  var topWin = window.top;
  var topDoc = topWin.document;
  var outer = topDoc.createElement("div");
  // Do not insert whitespace or outer.firstChild will get a text node.
  outer.innerHTML = 
    '<div style="position:absolute;z-index:' + __gwt_glassMessageZIndex-- +
    ';left:50px;top:50px;width:600px;color:#FFF;font-family:verdana;text-align:left;">' +
    '<div style="font-size:30px;font-weight:bold;">' + summary + '</div>' +
    '<div style="font-size:15px;">' + details + '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div style="position:absolute;z-index:' + __gwt_glassMessageZIndex-- +
    ';left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;filter:alpha(opacity=60);opacity:0.6;background-color:#000;"></div>'
  ;
  topDoc.body.appendChild(outer);
  var glass = outer.firstChild;
  var glassStyle = glass.style;

  // Scroll to the top and remove scrollbars.
  topWin.scrollTo(0, 0);
  if (topDoc.compatMode == "BackCompat") {
    topDoc.body.style["overflow"] = "hidden";
  } else {
    topDoc.documentElement.style["overflow"] = "hidden";
  }

  // Steal focus.
  glass.focus();

  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") >= 0) && (topDoc.compatMode == "BackCompat")) {
    // IE quirks mode doesn't support right/bottom, but does support this.
    glassStyle.width = "125%";
    glassStyle.height = "100%";
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 6") >= 0) {
    // IE6 doesn't have a real standards mode, so we have to use hacks.
    glassStyle.width = "125%"; // Get past scroll bar area.
    // Nasty CSS; onresize would be better but the outer window won't let us add a listener IE.
    glassStyle.setExpression("height", "document.documentElement.clientHeight");
  }

  $doc.title = summary + " [" + $doc.title + "]";
}

function findPluginObject() {
  try {
    return document.getElementById('pluginObject');
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

function findPluginEmbed() {
  try {
    return document.getElementById('pluginEmbed')
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

function findPluginXPCOM() {
  try {
    return __gwt_HostedModePlugin;
  } catch (e) {
    return null;
  }
}

gwtOnLoad = function(errFn, modName, modBase){
  $moduleName = modName;
  $moduleBase = modBase;

  // Note that the order is important
  var pluginFinders = [
    findPluginXPCOM,
    findPluginObject,
    findPluginEmbed,
  ];
  var topWin = window.top;
  var url = topWin.location.href;
  if (!topWin.__gwt_SessionID) {
    var ASCII_EXCLAMATION = 33;
    var ASCII_TILDE = 126;
    var chars = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
      chars.push(Math.floor(ASCII_EXCLAMATION
          + Math.random() * (ASCII_TILDE - ASCII_EXCLAMATION + 1)));
    }
    topWin.__gwt_SessionID = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, chars);
  }
  var plugin = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < pluginFinders.length; ++i) {
    try {
      var maybePlugin = pluginFinders[i]();
      if (maybePlugin != null && maybePlugin.init(window)) {
        plugin = maybePlugin;
        break;
      }
    } catch (e) {
    }
  }
  if (!plugin) {
    // try searching for a v1 plugin for backwards compatibility
    var found = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pluginFinders.length; ++i) {
      try {
        plugin = pluginFinders[i]();
        if (plugin != null && plugin.connect($hosted, $moduleName, window)) {
          return;
        }
      } catch (e) {
      }
    }
    loadIframe("http://www.gwtproject.org/missing-plugin/");
  } else {
    if (plugin.connect(url, topWin.__gwt_SessionID, $hosted, $moduleName,
        $hostedHtmlVersion)) {
      // take over the onunload function, wrapping any existing call if it exists
      var oldUnload = window.onunload;
      window.onunload = function() {
        // run wrapped unload first in case it is running gwt code
        !!oldUnload && oldUnload();
        try {
          // wrap in try/catch since plugins are not required to supply this
          plugin.disconnect();
        } catch (e) {
        }
      };
    } else {
      if (errFn) {
        errFn(modName);
      } else {
        __gwt_displayGlassMessage(
            "Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at " + simpleEscape($hosted),
            "Follow the troubleshooting instructions at "
            + "<a href='http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM'>"
            + "http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/TroubleshootingOOPHM</a>");
      }
    }
  }
}

function simpleEscape(originalString) {
  return originalString.replace(/&/g,"&amp;")
    .replace(/</g,"&lt;")
    .replace(/>/g,"&gt;")
    .replace(/\'/g, "&#39;")
    .replace(/\"/g,"&quot;");
}

// Lightweight metrics
window.fireOnModuleLoadStart = function(className) {
  $stats && $stats({moduleName:$moduleName, sessionId:$sessionId, subSystem:'startup', evtGroup:'moduleStartup', millis:(new Date()).getTime(), type:'onModuleLoadStart', className:className});
};

window.__gwt_module_id = 0;
</script></head>
<body>
<font face='arial' size='-1'>This html file is for Development Mode support.</font>
<script><!--
// Lightweight metrics
$stats && $stats({moduleName:$moduleName, sessionId:$sessionId, subSystem:'startup', evtGroup:'moduleStartup', millis:(new Date()).getTime(), type:'moduleEvalEnd'});

// OOPHM currently only supports IFrameLinker
var query = parent.location.search;
if (!findPluginXPCOM()) {
  document.write('<embed id="pluginEmbed" type="application/x-gwt-hosted-mode" width="10" height="10">');
  document.write('</embed>');
  document.write('<object id="pluginObject" CLASSID="CLSID:1D6156B6-002B-49E7-B5CA-C138FB843B4E">');
  document.write('</object>');
}

// look for the old query parameter if we don't find the new one
var idx = query.indexOf("gwt.codesvr=");
if (idx >= 0) {
  idx += 12;  // "gwt.codesvr=".length() == 12
} else {
  idx = query.indexOf("gwt.hosted=");
  if (idx >= 0) {
    idx += 11;  // "gwt.hosted=".length() == 11
  }
}
if (idx >= 0) {
  var amp = query.indexOf("&", idx);
  if (amp >= 0) {
    $hosted = query.substring(idx, amp);
  } else {
    $hosted = query.substring(idx);
  }

  // According to RFC 3986, some of this component's characters (e.g., ':')
  // are reserved and *may* be escaped.
  $hosted = decodeURIComponent($hosted);
}

query = window.location.search.substring(1);
if (query && $wnd[query]) setTimeout($wnd[query].onScriptLoad, 1);
--></script></body></html>
```

What do I do?

Comment: Post that `hosted.html`.

Comment: I added it to the original post, and it is here:  http://pastebin.com/jhuSYHe2

Comment: You have put the **entire** `war` folder on an `HTTP` server? What does that mean exactly. You served the `war` to the client??

Comment: Code needs to be posted in the question, not off on some off-site link.

Comment: I just put the entire WAR folder up so that the `hosted.html` could reference whatever it needs to via XMLHttpRequests and iframes or whatever else it may use.  I don't know what it needs, so there's no harm in giving it everything.  The `hosted.html` was served as `http://mydomain.se/WAR/mypackage/hosted.html`

Comment: I put the code in the question, it's just super long.

Comment: I am fairly sure this is **not** how this works. `hosted.html` is part of the internal functioning of GWT development mode. A `.war` is for deployment on a **Java EE** webserver, not an HTTP server. I would start by reading [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html) and then read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) on the new SuperDevMode. You should certainly not be accessing `hosted.html` directly.

Comment: check the name of your nocache.js and the one used in the html script tag. may be there is a typo.

Comment: The `hosted.html` file is part of dev mode itself, and is not required for the compiled app. Almost all of the other files in that same directory *are* required.